# "Disable" a <div> using the disable statement

Tags: html, css

i have this div

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="box17">
    <img src="images/dash/rh.jpg" alt="">
    <ul class="icon">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
    <div class="box-content">
     <h3 class="title">Recursos Humanos</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What i was tinking was add the disabled sentence in the div on the class "box17" like this

```
<div class="box17" disabled>
```

And change the backgroud in css with something like this

```
.box17:disabled{pointer-events:none;background:#e4e4e4}
```

But it does nothing, there is another way to "disable" the div?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the disabled tag? What exactly is on your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [div element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) supports [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) which does *not* include `disabled`. Use a class instead.

```
<div class="box17 disabled">

.box17.disabled{pointer-events:none;background:#e4e4e4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to that box div!

```css
div.box.disabled{
  backgorund: #e4e4e4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="box box17 disabled">
    <img src="images/dash/rh.jpg" alt="">
    <ul class="icon">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
    <div class="box-content">
     <h3 class="title">Recursos Humanos</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:disabled` pseudo class cannot be used on a class name. It is only applicable to `button`, `input`, `textarea`, `optgroup`, `option` and `fieldset`.

Use another class instead :

```
<div class="box17 disabled">
```

Then :

```
.box17.disabled {
    pointer-events:none;
    background:#e4e4e4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use disabled in divs. The only way to disable a div is to use pointer-events none

```
.disabled-content {
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Then your disabled div should be

```
<div class="disabled-content">Disabled div</div>
```